# c++ - How to use iterators in a pure virtual function of a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, virtual

I want to declare an interface class for a data processor with a method "process" that takes iterators as arguments: "start" and "end" point to the first and (behind the) last data item of type T to process, "destination" points at the position to which the processed data of type T shall be copied.

The goal is to subclass this interface and to let a factory decide which of the subclasses shall be created to process the data. This does not work if the interface can't be defined similar to the following:

```
template<typename T>
class Data_processor
{
public: 

    virtual void process_data(It_In start, It_In end, It_out destination) = 0;
};
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: If you want to work with "any" iterator in virtual context, you would need some type erasure. as there a re no virtual template method. For example, something like: `void process_data(std::function<std::optional<T>()> generator, std::function<void(T)> onElementProcessed)`

Comment: Why is the class a template? It doesn't have to be. And why isn't the `process_data` function a template? It needs to be since you don't know the iterator types.

Comment: What do you mean by "This does not work if..."? Also it's unclear to me what problem you're having. Additionally your template doesn't use `T`.

Comment: And it seems your code could use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) instead, and use a `process_data` function that takes the actual *data* and does some processing on it, returning the "new" and processed data. Or of the data should be left unmodified, just a `process_data` which takes a constant reference to some unknown type to "process".

Comment: Everything depends on requirements which are not described in this question. It is possible, but depending on details something has to be sacrificed: not a virtual function, limit to specific type of container (iterator), add some abstraction on iterator (slower code).

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post and I answer to all comments at once to clarify some points:
1. The class is a template because it is meant to be instanciated with different types: float, double, std::complex and so on.
2. The goal is to subclass this interface, including the process method. Of course, if the interface cannot be defined, the goal can't be reached.
3. The process method shall be used with iterators derived from different container types, e.g. std::vector<T> and std::list<T> and begin()/end().
4. The process method is not a template because template functions can't be virtual.

Comment: Can you use `boost`? [`any_range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html) is designed for this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code that will be calling `process_data` could instead call [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with the `Data_processor` as the *UnaryOperation*.

I.e. instead of

```
template<typename T>
class Data_processor
{
public: 

    virtual void process_data(It_In start, It_In end, It_out destination) = 0;
};

Data_processor<int> * processor = factory.make_processor<int>(args...);
processor->process_data(source.begin(), source.end(), dest.begin());
```

You would have

```
template<typename T>
class Data_processor
{
public: 

    virtual T operator()(T datum) = 0;
};

Data_processor<int> * processor = factory.make_processor<int>(args...);
std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), dest.begin(), std::ref(*processor));
```

However if there aren't any other members of `Data_processor`, you could use `std::function<T(T)>` instead.

```
std::function<int(int)> processor = factory.make_processor<int>(args...);
std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), dest.begin(), processor);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, the processed data can not be processed independently, i.e. some elements have to be shifted/exchanged, so the transform function can not be used here. My current solution is to use pointers T* instead.